# Microsoft Graph Api returns forbidden response when trying to use users/id/assignlicense in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

So, basically I have a multi-tenant App that makes numerous calls to Graph API. The problem is with the call to assign license to a user - POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/assignLicense.

In the Azure App registration portal , in the permissions section, I have given all the delegated permissions under Azure AD and Graph API.
[Permissions Assigned screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVeIG.png)

Then, I made an global admin consent to this app for all the users in the organization using admin consent flow through the link such as  below :-
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ffa835f3-417f-415c-b8f5-6f8833f93901&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8910%2f&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&prompt=admin_consent

The admin consent was successful which means that all users from this directory have been authorized.

Now, when I log to my multi-tenant application through a global admin, the call to assignLicense endpoint is a success which means my code is working well.

However, when a non Global Admin logs in to the application , he is able to login too ( due to the consent given above ) but when I call is made to the graph api to AssignLicense, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I am not able to understand what should I do to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an *effective permissions* issue. From https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

> For Delegated permissions, the effective permissions of your app will
>   be the least privileged intersection of the Delegated permissions the
>   app has been granted (via consent) and the privileges of the currently
>   signed-in user. Your app can never have more privileges than the
>   signed-in user. Within organizations, the privileges of the signed-in
>   user may be determined by policy or by membership in one or more
>   administrator roles. For more information about administrator roles,
>   see [Assigning administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles).
>
> For example, assume your app has been granted the User.ReadWrite.All
>   Delegated permission. This permission nominally grants your app
>   permission to read and update the profile of every user in an
>   organization. If the signed-in user is a global administrator, your
>   app will be able to update the profile of every user in the
>   organization. However, if the signed-in user is not in an
>   administrator role, your app will be able to update only the profile
>   of the signed-in user. It will not be able to update the profiles of
>   other users in the organization because the user that it has
>   permission to act on behalf of does not have those privileges.